# Programatically take screenshot of map extent in ArcMap 9.3

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap, c#, arcgis-9.3

Is it possible to programatically capture a screenshot of the current map extent (the map area with any active displayed layers) in ArcMap with the ArcObjects .NET SDK?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not necessary a screen shot, however here is how you can export the active view (refer to code snippet below).

[Export active view](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/ArcObjects_NET/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Sample_Export_active_view/000100000026000000/)